# Is limit of $f(x)^{g(x)}$ equivalent to limit of $f(x)$ raised to $g(x)$?

Tags: limits

The statement is that the limit of $f(x)^{g(x)}$ is equivalent to limit of $f(x)$ raised to $g(x)$.

I am solving exercises and using this, but I am unable to prove it.

I read it in a book as an important hint to solve the problems that followed, but can't find any text about it on the internet, so I would also like to know how can I search for this topic.

Comment: You mean raised to the limit of the exponent as well?

Comment: if exponent does not depend on $x$, it's OK to do this. Otherwise it's not true.

Answer (score 4):

$f(x)^{g(x)} = \exp(g(x) \ln(f(x))$, so if $f(x)$ has a positive finite limit $a$, and $g(x)$ has a finite limit $b$, then by continuity of $\ln$ and $\exp$, yes, $f(x)^{g(x)}$ tends to $a^{b}$

Answer (score 0):

Not always.

We have $0^0=1$, but $\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)=\lim_{x\to x-0} g(x)=0$ does not imply $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)^{g(x)}=1$. The problem is that the exponentiation map $(x,y)\mapsto x^y$ behaves somewhat weird on its maximal domain of definition. In particular, while *defined* for $(x,y)=(0,0)$ and a couple of other exceptional points, exponentiation is not *continuous* there (or even defined in a neighbourhood of $(0,0)$). On the other hand, for $a>0$ and $b\in \Bbb R$ arbitrary, exponentiation is defined and continuous in a neighbourhood of $(a,b)$. Therefore, in these cases, $f(x)\to a$ and $f(b)\to b$ implies $f(x)^{g(x)}\to a^b$.

Comment: I believe it's always said that we use $0^0$ only in some contexts, and not an universal truth.